# Objective C Enumerate Sentences in a paragraph

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4, text-segmentation

I would like to write an enumerator that would go through a paragraph of text and gives me one sentence at a time. I tried using stringEnumerate with the NSStringEnumerationBySentences but that simply looks at the periods and fails. For example, lets say I have the following text Block:

**"Senator John A. Boehner decided not to move forward. He also decided not to call the congress. The news reporter said though...."**

I would like my function to break down the above paragraph in the following sentences:

1. Senator John A. Boehner decided not to move forward
2. He also decided not to call the congress (No third sentence because it's a half a sentence)

The String Enumerator with the sentence optionjust looks at the periods and breaks down that way which is wrong:

1. Senator John A.
2. Boehner decided not to move forward
3. He also decided not to call the congress
4. The news reporter said though....

Is there any library or function that I can call that does a better job at this?

Thanks

```
- (NSMutableString *) getOnlyFullSentencesFromTextBlock:(NSMutableString *) textBlock{
    [textBlock enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [textBlock length])
                                  options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                                usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sentence Frag:%@", substring);                                                                        
    }];
    return textBlock;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need to iterate over them directly or would it be fine to get all the sentences into an array and iterate over that

Comment: You would need to define better what makes a sentence a sentence.  Its easy enough for humans to say that the sentence doesn't end at the first period because it is an abbreviation, but how does the computer know that?

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing what you're asking just by analyzing the string of characters.  You probably need something that understands English grammar reasonably well...perhaps the front end of an automatic translation system.

Comment: While what you want to do is possible, it is also very difficult. If you need a true language parser you must first understand what a language is. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language_theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language_theory). You will need to write many exceptions for known things like Mr. and Mrs. or Dr. etc.

Comment: You need some heuristics (which you must define), and there is (of course) a non-zero probability of making an error.

Comment: @PhillipMills -- I've done this sort of thing reasonably well with just a few rules and a list of exceptions.  It's mainly a matter of "training" the exception list based on "typical" input.

Comment: I actually compiled a list of 10000 abbreviation that will be converted to the real word before I run this. I thought maybe the sentence enumerator will be smarter than that & I dont have to run my own functions.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that occurs me is to check if the last word before the period begins with an uppercase character. If it does, and the number of characters of that word is no more than 3 or 4 (you will have to try to see what works better), probably it is an abbreviaion.

I know that this doesn't covers all the cases, but it may work for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

NSLinguisticTagger will do this